# Insert or copy huge records from DB2 to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-migration

I have one table in DB2 having number of records around: 99,000,000,000
I want to insert all records to SQL Server 2008 r2. What are the best possible ways to transfer this?

I have tried SSMA; however, SSMA is unable to fetch data. I tried linked server with OpenQuery and Select into. However, due to column datatype mismatch its not working as espected.

Please let me know the best possible ways? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain "its not working as espected"? That is a large number of rows for sure. I would think with that many rows you would want to use BULK INSERT.

Comment: I would dump the DB2 database to multiple text files, then use BCP to insert into SQL Server

Comment: @SeanLange How to use BULK INSERT? Would you prefer to use INSERT INTO in OpenQuery? If yes, would you suggest to make tables in SQL server same as DB2 then use BULK INSERT? Could you please give more idea?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx